# Как "замокать" объект, используемый внутри класса?

Tags: java, junit, testng, mockito

Всем привет!
Есть класс RegionController, в нём создаётся экземпляр класса DBRegionRepositoryImpl.
В RegionController вызывается метод getAll(), который в свою очередь вызывает метод getAll() экземпляра репозитория. Необходимо протестировать данный класс, "замокав" экзмепляр репозитория. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это правильно сделать?

```
public class RegionController {

    private final RegionRepository regionRepository;

    public RegionController() {
        this.regionRepository = new DBRegionRepositoryImpl();
    }
    public List<Region> getAll() {
        return regionRepository.getAll();
    }
```

Вот мой нерабочий тест:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RegionControllerTest {
    @Mock
    private RegionRepository regionRepository;
    @InjectMocks
    private RegionController regionController;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        List<Region> regions = new ArrayList<>();
        Region region = new Region("US");
        region.setId(1L);
        regions.add(region);
        when(regionRepository.getAll()).thenReturn(regions);

    @Test
    public void getAllTest() {
        List<Region> regionsForTest = new ArrayList<>();
        Region region = new Region("US");
        region.setId(1L);
        regionsForTest.add(region);
        List<Region> regions = regionController.getAll();
        assertEquals(regionsForTest.size(), regions.size());
        assertEquals(regionsForTest.get(0).getId(),
                regions.get(0).getId());
        assertEquals(regionsForTest.get(0).getName(),
                regions.get(0).getName());
       verify(regionRepository).getAll();
    }
```

Программа реализована через hibernate. При запуске теста выводятся логи hibernate и запрос к БД, но по идее такого быть не должно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того, чтобы замокать зависимость объекта нужно использовать паттерн Dependency Injection, хотя бы для тестов.

Можно добавить конструктор:

```
RegionController(RegionRepository regionRepository) {
    this.regionRepository = regionRepository;
}
```